# Implement an @html.myTelerikGrid extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm trying to do an HTML Extension to render my telerik grid with the common settings

If I declare this code into a view everything its fine.

```
@imports Telerik.Web.Mvc

@imports Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
 

@Code

Dim gridBuilder As Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridBuilder(Of TModel) =

Html.Telerik().Grid(Of TModel)().Name("myList")

@End Code
```

But I move it into a class library project to implement an HTML extension

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Imports Telerik.Web.Mvc

Imports Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI


Namespace Helpers

    Module HelperList

        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _

        Public Sub myTelerikList(Of TModel As Class)(helper As HtmlHelper)

            Dim gridBuilder As Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridBuilder(Of TModel) = Html.Telerik().Grid(Of TModel)().Name("myList")


…

…

        End Sub
```

I'm having an error like that

> 'Html' is ambiguous, imported from the
> namespaces or types
> 'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI, System.Web.Mvc'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the helper instance which you are extending:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Sub myTelerikList(Of TModel As Class)(helper As HtmlHelper)
    Dim gridBuilder As Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridBuilder(Of TModel) = helper.Telerik().Grid(Of TModel)().Name("myList")
    ...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `HtmlHelper` instance is named `helper`, you need to write `helper.Telerik()`.